# Which site for avatar related question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Recently, I just asked this question on Community Building: [Should the avatar of an organization in social networks be its logo?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1148/961). I have considered to ask it on:

- Graphic Design
- UX
- Community Building

and decide that the last one is the best suit. But I'm not very confident about that. Where should the questions about avatar go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that your question is suitable for any site on the Stack Exchange network, however of the three you mention Community Building would be the most suitable.

I think that any answer you get would be purely opinion based, however your question has been up-voted so others think it has value.

In general there's no one site that you can ask **all** avatar based questions on as there are so many aspects to them that no one site can accommodate them all.